# React native h.264 encoded video display

Tags: react-native, video

I am using react native and connected to PI camera. It's sending me h.264 encoded string in notification which is direct binary data. and I am trying to display this to video format. So, I am trying to find out how to display this stream as a video. and that string will update in every notification. and I found broadway (https://github.com/mbebenita/Broadway) player. which is for web view only and working perfect with my hardware. So, is there anything like this? which I can use to display h.264 encoded binary data to video using react native.

Comment: Any luck with this ?

Comment: Till now. there is no luck